# Grails Error: invalid XML character (Unicode: 0x5c)

Tags: xml, web-services, grails, groovy

I have done a little research on this problem but it seems that all the other answers include changing how the response get sent to you.  I am making a call to a third party webservice that returns with an xml string.  Which when I do on my local Win7 machine does just fine.  But when I put it out to our server, Win Server 2003, I get this error return:

```
Error 500: Executing action [vinlookup] of controller [AutoVehicleController] caused   exception: null
Servlet: grails
URI: /NonProfits/grails/autoVehicle/vinlookup.dispatch
Exception Message: An invalid XML character (Unicode: 0x5c) was found in the public identifier. 
Caused by: An invalid XML character (Unicode: 0x5c) was found in the public identifier. 
Class: AutoVehicleController 
At Line: [172] 
Code Snippet:
Stack Trace
org.xml.sax.SAXParseException: An invalid XML character (Unicode: 0x5c) was found in the public identifier.

    at org.apache.xerces.parsers.AbstractSAXParser.parse(Unknown Source)

    at org.apache.xerces.jaxp.SAXParserImpl$JAXPSAXParser.parse(Unknown Source)

    at VinPowerService.decodeVin(VinPowerService.groovy:40)

    at VinPowerService$$FastClassByCGLIB$$6f8d198b.invoke(&lt;generated&gt;)

    at net.sf.cglib.proxy.MethodProxy.invoke(MethodProxy.java:149)

    at VinPowerService$$EnhancerByCGLIB$$f1db38bd.decodeVin(&lt;generated&gt;)

    at VinPowerService$decodeVin.call(Unknown Source)

    at AutoVehicleController$_closure7.doCall(AutoVehicleController.groovy:172)

    at AutoVehicleController$_closure7.doCall(AutoVehicleController.groovy)

    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:619)
```

Comment: You don't say how your are calling the webservice, or show any code where this error is thrown, or say which version of Grails and related plugins you are using...  It might be useful?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The message is pretty explicit:

> An invalid XML character (Unicode: 0x5c) was found in the public
>   identifier.

The "public identifier" is the string that appears after the keyword PUBLIC in the DOCTYPE declaration. There are rules as to what characters can appear in the public identifier, and backslash is not allowed.

You have a choice. Persuade the people who generated this identifier to mend their ways, or write some kind of script that repairs the bad XML on receipt. It's unlikely that anyone cares what the value of the public identifier is, so you can probably just delete the backslash without doing any damage.

Answer (score 1):

0x5c is the "whack" character `\`, which can be used for "escape sequences". As such it needs to be escaped itself, for XML content. There should be a helper function like HTMLEncode (drawing from memory here), which converts all such characters to their "escaped versions" (i.e. `&` becomes `&amp;`).

Comment: The ``\`` is not used for escaping in XML.  It's a normal punctuation character.  It's not valid in a name token (e.g. tag name or attribute name) though, which only allows certain punctuation characters.

Comment: Perhaps this is applicable? [link](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5858684/getting-jdomexception-on-one-machine-but-the-same-xml-works-fine-in-another)

Answer (score 0):

if your XML is in good format, verify you don't to have a whitespace after the first node. Server returns a string, but it wants to add whitespaces before, and, an error was occured...